# Search for repeated occurences of a certain substring in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I'd like to search only for repeated occurences of a string that starts e.g. with the pattern `possible` in a given input file.

- Example Input:

  ```
  this is the best possible solution
  possible1234 solution!!!
  possible5678 solution!!!
  possible5678 solution!!!
  possible0000 solution!
  possible0000 solution!
  There should be some "possible7777" solution!
  There should be some "possible7777" solution!
  ```
- Desired output:

  ```
  possible5678 solution!!!
  possible0000 solution!
  There should be some "possible7777" solution!
  ```

  because this is a pattern matching `possibleNNNN` that occurs multiple times in the file.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like homework. What have you tried on your own so far? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: it is not a homework, i m trying to grep the logs from the server, where string for ex: "abc" repeats more than n times for ex, but i dont know how to do it.
I have already stored all "abc" in a file.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The best thing would be if you could edit your question to provide a minimum representative input example along with the desired output.

Comment: I have tried to rephase your question to make it easier to understand. Still, please have a look and ensure it is what you want. Also, does the pattern (in your example `possibleNNNN`) always occur as a separate word, or could there be strings like `thisisaveryafwulbutpossible1234occurence` or `this is possible1234!` in your file? If so, would you want to output that, too? Do the strings you are looking for always occur at the beginning of a line, or can they be anywhere?

Comment: In the above mentioned case the pattern starts with "possible" but after that it can be any numerical number, like "this is possible1234!".

The output should all the repetative cases of possibleXXXX (XXX can be any numerical value).

Comment: I see. And you only want to output the `1234` part? Will the `possible` part be at the start of a separate word, or could it also be something like `impossible1234`?

Comment: Actually i need output possibleXXXX, and i dont know how to grep the repetation of XXXX, (the value XXXX can be any numerical value which i cant tell) the part starts with "possible" or but sometimes could also be "impossible1234".

Comment: It's not clear if you want one of the set of lines with a duplicate `possibleXXX` value output or a duplicate line that contains any `possibleXXX` value output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These give possible approaches to address some of [the different revisions of your question](/posts/598412/revisions):

```
<your-file grep '^possible[[:digit:]]' | sort | uniq -d
```

Would give you a lexically sorted list of duplicate lines that start with `possible<digit>`.

- `grep` selects the lines that start with `possible` followed by at least one digit.
- `sort` sorts the result so that duplicates are adjacent (needed for `uniq`).
- `uniq -d` reports duplicates.

---

To match on any occurrence of `possible<digits>` wherever they are in the input, assuming the GNU implementation of `grep` or compatible:

```
<your-file grep -Po 'possible\d+' | sort | uniq -d
```

On an input like:

```
possible123xx impossible123yy
```

That would give:

```
possible123
```

---

For all the unique lines that contain a duplicated `possible<digit>`:

```
perl -lne 'if (/possible(\d+)/) {
             $count{$1}++;
             $lines{$1}->{$_}++;
           }
           END{
             for $k (grep {$count{$_} > 1} keys %count) {
               print for keys %{$lines{$k}}
             }
           }' < your-file
```

On an input like:

```
this is the best possible solution
possible1234 solution!!!
possible5678 solution!!!
possible5678 solution!!!
possible0000 solution!
impossible0000 other solution!
```

It gives:

```
possible0000 solution!
impossible0000 other solution!
possible5678 solution!!!
```

(in no defined order other than lines for a given `possibleXXXX` will be next to each other).

Comment: I tried it, this works like a "cut -b", but i would like to have the whole line as mentioned above.

Comment: @shivashiva, see edit.

Comment: you are just Genius!!!. thanks a lot, this is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

For your revised example, an `awk`-based solution could work:

```
awk '/possible[[:digit:]]+/ {count[$0]++;} END{for (line in count) {if (count[line]>1) print line}}' input.txt
```

or, if your `awk` doesn't understand POSIX character classes

```
awk '/possible[0-9]+/ {count[$0]++;} END{for (line in count) {if (count[line]>1) print line}}' input.txt
```

This would check every line if it contains the pattern `possible` followed by at least one digit. If found, it will increase an occurence counter *for the entire line*. In the end, it will only print those lines where the occurence counter is larger than 1.

Note that this will only work if your actual input is as shown. If there can be the same `possibleNNNN` pattern on different lines, it will fail!

Comment: yes you are right, I tried it, may be i need to change my question again with more ex.

Comment: @shivashiva This `awk` approach should do what your current example requires, only the output is not necessarily in the same order as the lines appear in your file initially.

Comment: I tired like this but doesnt return anything.

awk '/90100[[:digit:]]+/ {count[$0]++;} END{for (line in count) {if (count[line]>1) print line}}' filename.log

Comment: Try to replace the `[[:digit:]]` with `[0-9]` (literally, i.e. no more double brackets, either).

Comment: awk '/90100[0-9]+/ {count[$0]++;} END{for (line in count) {if (count[line]>1) print line}}' filename.log |less

Answer (score 1):

We may use the following approach which preserves the order of the dup lines.

Store the regex into an environmental variable "re" then look for the regex line using the match command. On thoise lines we update the count of the regex seen till then by means of the gsub command.

```
$ re='\<possible[0-9]+\>' \
awk  'BEGIN { r = ENVIRON["re"] }
match($0, r) && 
(a[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)] += gsub(r, "&")) == 2'  logfile
```

A one liner in Perl  wiil be:

```
perl -lne 'print if /\bpossible(\d+)\b/ && 2 == ($h{$1} +=()= //g)' logfile
```

Comment: You should mention that the awk solution requires GNU awk for those word boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below awk simple command

```
awk '{if(seen[$0]++){print $0}}' file
```

output

```
possible5678 solution!!!
possible0000 solution!
There should be some "possible7777" solution!
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
uni=[]
full_with_duplicate=[]
k=open('p.txt','r')
for i in k:
    if i.strip() not in uni:
        uni.append(i.strip())
t=open('p.txt','r')
for i in t:
    full_with_duplicate.append(i.strip())


for i in uni:
    if full_with_duplicate.count(i) > 1:
        print i
```

output

```
possible5678 solution!!!
possible0000 solution!
There should be some "possible7777" solution!
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for `\<` word boundary, `\w` shorthand, and the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/\<possible\w*/,a) && ++cnt[a[0]]==2' file
possible5678 solution!!!
possible0000 solution!
There should be some "possible7777" solution!
```

You didn't say WHICH line with a duplicate key you wanted output so the above outputs the 2nd one.